# LINUX: How to find(grep) for a file starting at the root?

Tags: linux, terminal, grep, root

I'm trying to find all c files in /usr and its subdirectories that contain "main" but I cant figure out how to make it start searching from the root. I am assuming that the current directory is not in or is usr.
So i tried
grep -r "main" /usr/*.c
Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find /usr -name "*.c" -exec grep -l main {} \;
```

Is the simple minded version that individually greps each .c file in /usr and outputs it's name.

You could improve it by using `xargs` to reduce the calls to grep:

```
find /usr -name "*.c" | xargs grep -l main
```

Comment: You can also do `find ... -exec grep -l main () +`. Using `+` instead of `\;` tells find to run the command with multiple filenames, similar to the way xargs works.

Comment: Nice: didn't know that trick!

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERETOLOOK=/
find $WHERETOLOOK -type f -iname "*.c" | xargs grep main

EXAMPLES:

$ find / -type f -iname "*.txt" 2> /dev/null | xargs grep INST | head -n 3
grep: /opt/android-sdk/SDK/opt/sun-jdk-1.6.0.33/db/demo/programs/vtis/data/svn_log.txt:Adding message for DATA_SQLDATA_READ_INSTANTIATION_EXCEPTION.
/opt/sun-jdk-1.6.0.33/db/demo/programs/vtis/data/svn_log.txt:        - When a log record is encountered, set newFileStart to INVALID_LOG_INSTANT.
/opt/android-sdk/platforms/android-10/images/NOTICE.txt:DOWNLOADING, INSTALLING, COPYING OR OTHERWISE USING UNICODE INC.'S DATA

$ find /usr/share/ -type f -iname "*.txt" | xargs grep INST | head -n 3
/usr/share/games/holotz-castle/game/menu/sv/menu.txt:INSTÄLLNINGAR
/usr/share/webapps/phpmyadmin/3.5.2.2/postinst-en.txt:   mkdir ${MY_INSTALLDIR}/config
/usr/share/webapps/phpmyadmin/3.5.2.2/postinst-en.txt:   chown ${VHOST_SERVER_UID}:${VHOST_SERVER_UID} ${MY_INSTALLDIR}/config
xargs: grep: terminated by signal 13
```

Answer (score 0):

If you installed [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) (known as ack-grep in Debian/Ubuntu), you could simply run `ack -l --cc main` from /usr and you'd get your result.